# JSF 2 - Where does a @ViewScoped bean live between requests?

Tags: java, serialization, jsf-2, scope, managed-bean

I'm trying to better understand the low-level workings of a `@ViewScoped` bean in JSF 2. Where does the server keep the view-scoped bean between requests? I've noticed that my view-scoped beans need to implement `Serializable`, so they must get serialized to some location.

**Can anyone explain this or provide a link to documentation that explains it?**

I'm asking the question because I may have introduced a scope-related defect into my webapp.  Understanding how `@ViewScoped` works will help me rule out some of the potential causes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@ViewScoped beans are stored in the viewMap of the UIViewRoot:

> UIViewRoot is the UIComponent that represents the root of the
>   UIComponent tree. This component renders markup as the response to
>   Ajax requests. It also serves as the root of the component tree...

In fact, you can access this viewMap yourself, and stuff values in there using:

```
facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewMap()...
```

For more information, see the JSF API doc:
http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html